# Can I run several iOS UI Tests in Parallel?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I'm working on building a UI Test suite for my iOS app. I need to test my app's functionality on several different devices, but right now I have to select the simulator I want, run the tests, and then repeat.

Now that Xcode supports multiple simulators running in parallel, is there a way to run the UI tests across several different device simulators at the same time?

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/linkedin/bluepill ?

Comment: I was able to this by following this guide: https://medium.com/@t.camin/parallelizing-ui-tests-28c16000f141.

Answer (score 5):

Run the following command in the same directory as your project to run your tests in parallel from the command line:

```
xcodebuild test -scheme "YourSchemeName" -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=11.2,name=iPhone 8' -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=11.2,name=iPhone 6s'  -configuration "Debug" ENABLE_TESTABILITY=YES SWIFT_VERSION=4.0 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES
```

You can add `-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=11.2,name=iPhone 8'` for a different destination for as many different destinations as you would like.

For a list of simulator names and OSs that are available, run the command:

```
instruments -s devices
```

Bear in mind that if you are running tests in the simulator, you will not see the simulators on your screen when running tests through the command line.

Comment: For Xcode 13 and later, use `xctrace list devices` instead. (`instruments` has been removed.)

Answer (score 2):

## In Xcode:

1. Select your target scheme in Xcode, and "Edit Scheme..."
2. Find the settings for "Test", and press on the "Info" tab
3. You'll see a list of your Unit and UI tests, press on the associated
   "Options..." button
4. Select "Execute in parallel on Simulator"
5. Optionally select "Randomize execution order"

[image: Enable Parallel Testing]

---

## Commandline:

Look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47790996/5623035)